# C# ListItemCollection to JSON, while keeping values and text items

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, json

I have created a web service (asmx file) that returns a serialized ListItemCollection with the following code.

```
    public string getStates(string Country)
    {
        ListItemCollection lic = DBInterface.GetStates(Country);

        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lic);

        return serialized;
    }
```

I call the web service via javascript when a user selects a country from a dropdown list using the following code.

```
            //ajax function that uses web services to get states
        function GetStates(val)
        {                  
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebServices/getServerData.asmx/getStates",
                data: JSON.stringify({Country: val}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ddlState").empty();
                    var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
                    for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
                        $("#ddlState").append("<option value='" + parsed[i] + "'>" + parsed[i] + "</option>");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data.status + " " + data.statusText);
                }
            });                    
        }
```

The issue is that I want to also keep not only the ListItemCollection text, but also it's value. However the "JsonConvert.SerializeObject only returns the text items. Can someone help to return the value and text so that I can populate the dropdown via javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: could you please explain what do you mean by value

Comment: Well a ListItemCollection is composed of many ListItems (its an array of list items), list items have a text property as well as a value property. When you bind a ListItemCollection to a dropdown list every item in there will have a text and value property binded. For example the city "Texas" has an item value of 23443 (which I used as a key on my database). I am not familiar much with JSON objects however I see that the SerializeObject creates a whole bunch of items such as {"Texas","Louisiana",...} I would like it to be something like {
    "Value": 2344,
    "Text": "Texas"
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can use the `JavaScriptSerializer()` in `System.Web.Script.Serialization`:

```
ListItemCollection lic = new ListItemCollection() {
    new ListItem("Display Text", "val1"),
    new ListItem("Display Text 2", "val2"),
};

var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var serialized = ser.Serialize(lic);
```

Results in (I took the liberty to format) :

```
[
    {
        "Attributes": {
            "Keys": [],
            "Count": 0,
            "CssStyle": {
                "Keys": [],
                "Count": 0,
                "Value": null
            }
        },
        "Enabled": true,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Display Text",
        "Value": "val1"
    },
    {
        "Attributes": {
            "Keys": [],
            "Count": 0,
            "CssStyle": {
                "Keys": [],
                "Count": 0,
                "Value": null
            }
        },
        "Enabled": true,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Display Text 2",
        "Value": "val2"
    }
]
```

Comment: this could do the job

Comment: This got the data back perfectly! Thanks, by the way I hate asking a question about this but how do you read it in javascript correctly? Am I on the right track according to the above?

Comment: @Eliseo I don't believe you need to parse the response from the server since you passed in `dataType: 'json'`, but it looks sound otherwise.